# Ubuntu IKEv1 IPSec alternative to strongSwan

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, ipsec, strongswan

I'm trying to connect to my work VPN which uses IKEv1/IPSec and authenticates with a preshared key however it appears strongSwan has a PSK limitation restricting PSKs to 20 characters or longer (even though this is the client side...). See bug reference [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-strongswan/+bug/1697536). Unfortunately the PSK my work uses is under 20 characters and I cannot change that.

Is there a recommended active alternative to strongSwan that would allow me to connect to my work VPN from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS? In my searching I've come across *racoon*, *VPNC*, and the official Cisco client, but the consensus seems to be the Cisco client is rather unwieldy and the former too seem outdated at this point.

Alternatively, if anyone knows a way to get around the 20 character PSK limit of strongSwan that would of course work too.

Thanks

Comment: There's also this written: "I guess you are referring to IKEv1 XAuth/PSK. The strongSwan NetworkManager plugin does not support this". You could give a shot at libreswan: https://libreswan.org/wiki/VPN_server_for_remote_clients_using_IKEv1_XAUTH_with_PSK with a very good introduction "Using XAUTH PSK is the least secure mode of running IKE/IPsec.". See also: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreswan/+bug/1692066